# ng-repeat not working in firefox that worked perfectly in chrome

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="timeline in timeline_events">
    <div class="span3 span3-min"><p>{{timeline.link}}</p></div>
    <div class="span2 span2-min"><p>{{timeline.other}}</p></div>
    <div class="span2 span2-min"><p>{{timeline.description}}</p></div>
    <div class="span1 span1-min">
        <p>
            <a class='del-timeline' ng-click='delTimeline($index)'>X</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The timeline_events are rendering perfectly in chrome but not in firefox.I have cleared session and checked.NO result.What might be the issue??

UPDATE: So I am accessing timeline_events through ajax request.Firefox if not rendering any ng-repeat directive if I am fetching value through ajax.Working perfect in chrome and safari.Any remedy??

Comment: did you try to figure out if there are any exceptions or error by using firebug? anything in the console?
Are you able to reproduce your problem in a jsfiddle or sth similar?

Comment: @alfrescian I checked firebug.No issue.If value is fetching via ajax, ng-repeat is not rendering in firefox

Answer (score 1):

here is a JS Fiddle of your code ,it should also work in firefox:

```
<div ng-controller='mainCtrl' class="container">
<div class="row-fluid" ng-repeat="timeline in timeline_events">
    <div class="span3 span3-min">
        <p>{{timeline.link}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 span2-min">
        <p>{{timeline.other}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span2 span2-min">
        <p>{{timeline.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span1 span1-min">
        <p> <a class='del-timeline' ng-click='delTimeline($index)'>X</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.timeline_events = [{
        link: 'link 1',
        other: 'other 1',
        description: 'description 1'
    }, {
        link: 'link 2',
        other: 'other 2',
        description: 'description 2'
    }, {
        link: 'link 3',
        other: 'other 3',
        description: 'description 3'
    }];
    $scope.delTimeline = function (index) {
        $scope.timeline_events.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alfrescian/5hVmc/

Comment: This is working like a charm..But not mine.I tried with some other firefox and is working.Might a problem with this version of firefox.I installed firefox yesterday.Thanks for your time